# Styling a horizontal nav

Tags: html, css, html-lists, margin, display

I am working on this site where users can click on a subject and it brings up a "stack" of digital Spanish to English flash cards.

I have the list of vocab categories (colors, greetings, food, etc.). I want to display it as a horizontal list, but when I change the display to inline, the li elements overlap. How do I fix this? I want to make it so that they never overlap, even when the width of the page changes. I tried to add margin-top and margin-bottom CSS styles, but that doesn't do anything.

Here is my Code:

```css
li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 border: 3px solid black;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 width: 180px;
 background-color: rgb(0,103,255);
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav id="subjectlist">
  <ul>
    <li id="subjone">Colors</li>
    <li id="subjtwo">People and Family</li>
    <li id="greetings">Greetings</li>
    <li id="bodyparts">Body Parts</li>
    <li id="food">Food</li>
    <li id="animals">Animals</li>
    <li id="days">Days of the Week</li>
    <li id="months">Months of the Year</li>
    <li id="seasons">Seasons</li>
    <li id="weather">Weather</li>
    <li id="householdobjects">Household Objects</li>
    <li id="clothing">Clothing</li>
    <li id="sports">Sports</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try using `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `display` property to `inline-block`

```css
li {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
border: 3px solid black;
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 180px;
background-color: rgb(0,103,255);
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <nav id="subjectlist">
            <ul>
                <li id="subjone">Colors</li>
                <li id="subjtwo">People and Family</li>
                <li id="greetings">Greetings</li>
                <li id="bodyparts">Body Parts</li>
                <li id="food">Food</li>
                <li id="animals">Animals</li>
                <li id="days">Days of the Week</li>
                <li id="months">Months of the Year</li>
                <li id="seasons">Seasons</li>
                <li id="weather">Weather</li>
                <li id="householdobjects">Household Objects</li>
                <li id="clothing">Clothing</li>
                <li id="sports">Sports</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** here. Just make your `<ul>` a flex container. And remove `display: inline` from `<li>`s.

like:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex; /* Flex Container */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* Wrap to next line */
}

li {
/*   display: inline; */
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 3px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: rgb(0,103,255);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav id="subjectlist">
            <ul>
                <li id="subjone">Colors</li>
                <li id="subjtwo">People and Family</li>
                <li id="greetings">Greetings</li>
                <li id="bodyparts">Body Parts</li>
                <li id="food">Food</li>
                <li id="animals">Animals</li>
                <li id="days">Days of the Week</li>
                <li id="months">Months of the Year</li>
                <li id="seasons">Seasons</li>
                <li id="weather">Weather</li>
                <li id="householdobjects">Household Objects</li>
                <li id="clothing">Clothing</li>
                <li id="sports">Sports</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Hope this helps!